# Using get for a list containing multiple vectors

Tags: clojure

Lets say I define classA as the following:

```
(def classA ["John" "16"])
```

If I wanted to get information from the vector I would call

```
(get classA 0) ;; => "John"
(get classA 1) ;; => "16"
```

Now say I define classB as:

```
(def classB '(["John" "16"] ["Simon" "17"] ["Peter" "16"]))
```

How would I get the information "John" out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first` to get the first vector in the list:

```
(get (first classB) 0)
```

Since you want the first item of the inner collection you could use first there too:

```
(first (first classB))
```

or just `ffirst`:

```
(ffirst classB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider get-in if your input supports index access.  E.g.

```
(def classB [["John" "16"] ["Simon" "17"] ["Peter" "16"]])

(get-in classB [0 0]) => "John"

(get-in classB [1 1]) => "17"
```